# Apache Wicket Quick Start

Tags: eclipse, jetty, wicket

I was trying to start learning about Apache Wicket (as it looked like an easy to use UI for Java) and as I like to work with Eclipse and Maven. I also like to work with Tomcat, however, Wicket seems to prefer Jetty at least in its tutorials. I do not know nothing about Jetty, however should not take ages to learn.

I tried the [Wicket Quick Start](https://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html.) and successfully imported the generated Maven project to Eclipse workspace.

But errors appear: e.g.

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration;

**It seems Eclipse cannot find the jetty server classes. How to add these to the Eclipse project?**

Does the creater of the Wicket Quick Start assumed that Jetty is already installed on the machine?
*I installed it. However: what is the recommended way to make what jar file available to a maven project to have jetty server classes available? I would assume via the pom.xml but I doubt that is the case here - the given pom.xml would contain it.*

Or is there some special plugin for Eclipse (Photon)?
*Run-Jetty-Run?. I wasn't brave enough to try that.*

I would love to get the Wicket Quick Start running.

I also tried [Eclipse + Tomcat + Apache Wicket Maven Setup with Hello World Example](http://digitalappconsultancy.com/site/eclipse-tomcat-apache-wicket-maven-setup-with-hello-world-example/) but it seems that it is outdated. I was not able to install qwickie to Eclipse as described.

I am using Eclipse Proton with Java 10.0.2 on Debian Stretch.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using https://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html then you can start the application these ways:

1. `mvn jetty:run` - this will use `jetty-maven-plugin`
2. Open in Eclipse `src/test/java/com/example/Start.java` and run it as a normal Java class with a `main(String[])` method. This will use Jetty Maven dependencies to start an embedded Jetty server.

Wicket's Quickstart prefers Jetty because Jetty developers made it easy to use it in *non production way*, i.e. in development mode, for faster dev cycles. No need to build a .war file and deploy it.

On the other side Tomcat devs (disclaimer: I am a member of both Wicket and Tomcat teams) never spent time in this direction. Tomcat's Maven plugin has been abandoned long time ago. The best integration for starting embedded Tomcat is provided by Spring Boot project (I recommend it if you use Spring!).

So, just remove the Jetty related dependencies and plugin in pom.xml and the Start.java in `src/test/java/...`. Then you can continue developing with Eclipse and Tomcat the way you like to do it.